# files not listing when using xp_dirtree for remote path?

Tags: sql-server

trying to list the files from folder which is in remote server. xp_dirtree is listing files from local folder but showing empty for folder which is in remote server. I did google on this but did not get the solution to fix. please anyone could suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check access to to that remote folder, for service account SQL Server is running. If not you will get empty results

Comment: where can I check this? is it in services.msc?

Comment: Check what service account, service is running, and try accessing that account from normal windows to access that path

Comment: Perhaps you could make a stored procedure on the remote server that gives you this information, then simply call the SP?

Comment: service account is NT service. how to access this account from normal windows?